# Excel: Screenshot automatically pastes to another sheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have here my draft code of screen shot for my sheet.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

shtAnalysis.Range("A10:U36").CopyPicture format:=xlBitmap
MsgBox "Snapshot copied to clipboard!", vbInformation Or vbOKOnly, "Snapshot"

End Sub
```

What I'm aiming to do is when you click the button for screen shot
The code will do the screen shot and will paste it into another new sheet.

I have 2 Sheets,
the first sheet, ***Analysis*** (Where the button for screen shot located)
the second sheet, ***Checking*** (Where the screen shot will be placed)

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro while performing the copy/paste process?

Comment: Yes sir, I tried to record a macro. Just testing it first before doing the macro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your destination sheet (Checking) is in a variable named shtChecking, you can do it this way:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    shtAnalysis.Range("A10:U36").CopyPicture format:=xlBitmap
    MsgBox "Snapshot copied to clipboard!", vbInformation Or vbOKOnly, "Snapshot"
    shtChecking.Paste Destination:=shtChecking.Range("F5")
End Sub
```

If you want to align the image with the cell "F5", in example